# How to delete files with different extensions according to a specific condition?

Tags: bash, shell, file

Although there are [several quite similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete%20files%20with%20different%20extensions&s=690f5d86-4921-40fd-9f67-692603a87332) I could not apply the answer to my problem:

I have a lot of txt-files with a corresponding tsv-file of the same name but with different extensions, for example

```
$ ls myDirectory
file1.tsv        (empty)
file1.txt
file2.tsv        (not empty)
file2.txt
```

Only if the tsv-file is empty, I would like to delete both files. If the tsv-file is not empty, I would like to keep both files. Like so:

```
$ ls myDirectory
file2.tsv
file2.txt
```

Alternatively, I would like to delete both corresponding files if and only if a specific string is not contained in the txt-file? (In case that is easier.)

How can that be done with a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over tsv files. Check the existence of the corresponding txt file, if it's there but the tsv is empty, remove them.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
for tsv in *.tsv ; do
    txt=${tsv%.tsv}.txt        # Corresponding txt file.
    [[ -f $txt ]] || continue  # Skip tsv if txt doesn't exist.
    if [[ ! -s $tsv ]] ; then  # If tsv is empty
        rm "$tsv" "$txt"       #   remove both.
    fi
done
```

The alternative can be implemented in a similar way, just use a different condition in the if-clause:

```sh
    if ! grep -q "$search" "$txt" ; then
```

where $search contains the regex you want to search for.